# How to parse XML using databricks in Spark Java

Tags: java, parsing, databricks

I need to parse XML file using databricks in Spark.

I want to show the result for attribute Count=7.

> I want to get the output: 
>   soccer

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
<row Id="1" TagName="soccer" Count="7" ExcerptPostId="12371" WikiPostId="12370" />
<row Id="2" TagName="servos" Count="63" ExcerptPostId="186" WikiPostId="185" />
<row Id="3" TagName="control" Count="394" ExcerptPostId="192" WikiPostId="191" />
<row Id="5" TagName="gait" Count="4" ExcerptPostId="12362" WikiPostId="12361" />
</tags>
```

My Main class (but it doesn't work properly):

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader;

public class SimpleApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String someFile = "/home/files/Tags.xml";

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple app").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<String> logData = spark.read().textFile(someFile).cache();

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read.xml("/home/files/Tags.xml");
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("tags", "Count")
            .load("/home/files/Tags.xml");

    df.select("TagName", "Count").write()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("tags", "TagName")
            .save("/home/files/Tags.xml");

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this [jaxb tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: @VictorGubin thank you, but I can't find examples for using databricks

Comment: You mean xml dada-source -  hire it is https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml, see Java API section

Comment: @VictorGubin I tried but it doesn't work for me